# ASP MVC 5 Routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an ASP MVC  5 Application, and i'm using routing attributes, i have a Demo action in a Company Controller, this action is a default action for my web site :

When i run the web site everything is good and the default action is the Demo action, but in the navigation bar of my browser the url is : localhost/:54973/, what changes i have to do to get an url like : localhost/:54973/Company/Demo/isin

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("~/", Name = "default")]
        [Route("Demo/{isin}")]
        public ActionResult Demo(string isin= "isin")
{
//code
}
```

Comment: Switch the attributes for `Route`. The more specific one should be on top.

Comment: Do you mean      [Route("Demo/{isin}")]  then                                          [Route("~/", Name = "default")] ?

Comment: yes.  That should do it.

Comment: that what i did exactly but unfortunately it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method.

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("Company/Demo/{isin}")]        
        public ActionResult Demo(string isin= "isin")
{
//code
}
```

Comment: This redirect to the Demo action, but my problem is that in the navigation bar of my browser i haven't the complete URL, i have just localhost:54973 but i want the complete URL will be displayed : localhost:54973/Comany/demo/isin

Comment: i have just change the web project start URL property, to http://localhost:54973/Company/Demo/isin and that works fine :)